# Images compatible to all iPads?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

It seems like a simple question, and it is, but I somehow could not find the answer in google. 
We want to port our game to the `iPad`. We don't want to make many of the same images for `retina/non-retina` display. We prefer 1 set of images that will be compatible with all of them.

1. What size should we pick for a full background, to be compatible with all iPads in full screen?
   (if we use the iPad2 1024x768 , will it fit to iPad3-retina, and iPad mini, in full screen? )
   What do most developers usually do? Do they have a set of graphics for ALL iPad screens? isn't it making the app huge?
2. What will be the suffix of this 1 set of images with `cocos2d`, to be compatible with all screens? `-hd`?

3.Can we be sure if we check it on `iPad2`, to be working with the rest of them? (we can't buy all iPads, only check on simulator).

Thanks very much .

Comment: A low resolution image won't look very good on a retina iPad, so you'll want to go with high resolution. I'm not sure whether cocos2d will scale images down though. As for testing; if you don't test on all iPads/OS versions there are no guarantees anyone can make, although if you test on at least the major versions of the OS you want to support and one retina/one non retina iPad, it's at least fairly likely to work elsewhere.

Comment: So you usually make all images to support retina and non retina? isn't it makes the app too big ??

Comment: An iPad2 can (with some exceptions) use iPad3+ images without a problem. The reason for adding low resolution images is mainly performance and memory use concerns. If that's not a problem for your game, you may get away with high res only.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks, but i don't get that. if i set high resolution image, which is twice the ipad2 resolution(768x1024), so the iPad3 use the retina resizing,and it looks great, but ipad2 will take the images as they are , so i will see only part of them , no ? what am i missing here ?

Comment: Most components that contain images can scale to fill, so the images will show up correctly, even if more slowly.

Comment: I dont enable retina for retina iPads and use my -hd pics. Price to pay, i have to place them by hand in my code, and my backgrounds are all 1136x768. Looks great. Some tips : higher color saturation if possible, make certain you process your files with dithering filters to eliminate banding on slow color gradient areas of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Use just Double size images named them as image@2x.

For Example : **1024x768** image name is **test.png**  and **2048x1536** image name is **test@2x.png**.

Then it will work in all types of iPad. Ipad mini adjust automatically.

Comment: careful, this means 4x texture memory usage on non-retina ipads, and the ipad 2 has only half the memory of Retina ipads

Comment: if your application is local means , it does not using images from any Server then ,yes you have to put both images whether it is iPad 2 or 3.But if the images came from server then you can put validation for retina display and download image accordingly.